# Symfony, query increases page load by ten times

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a custom voter, which loads on every http request. Which it should, because it should grant access to the user, or deny (or abstain). This query should load every time, only when certain variables in the session are set. So I wrote exception and all, but even when this query runs one time. It takes ten times more time to load the page. And the weird thing is, this query is really simple.

My vote function:

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{

    $result = VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

    $academy = $object;
    // object is not an academy, so get it from the context manager
    if (!$academy instanceof Academy) {
        $academy = $this->context_manager->getAcademy();

        // no academy means this voter is useless
        if (!$academy instanceof Academy)
            return $result;
    }

    // get the current user
    $user = $token->getUser();

    // no user, not a valid user, or user has no academy role, voter abstains
    if (!$user || !($user instanceof UserInterface) || !$user->hasRole('ROLE_ACADEMY'))
        return $result;

    // this is the function which increases page load
    $permissions = $this->manager->findPermissionsByUserAndAcademy($academy, $user); 
    ...
```

That function is a normal doctrine function:

```
public function findPermissionsByUserAndAcademy(Academy $academy, User $user)
{

    $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AcademyUsers');
    $academyUsers = $repository->findOneBy(array(
        'academy' => $academy,
        'user' => $user));

    $permissions = $academyUsers->getAcademyRole()->getPermissions();

    return $permissions;
}
```

if I comment the function, everything works as it should, but when it runs, every page takes 10 times to load.

Comment: It may look simple, but it might actually not be as much. Relationships matter, and if given, amount of records as well and much more. What is the difference in executed queries number when you hit the page with and without this query?

Comment: @Artamiel it was indeed running way too much. Twenty time the same query. I didn't thought that that would be the problem, but it was.